# How can I rotate ExoPlayer when not using a texture surface and without rotating the controls?

Tags: android, exoplayer, exoplayer2.x

I have two problems with rotating ExoPlayer. I've researched it a bit and most suggestions are to use `texture_view` but that won't work for my case, plus it messes up the controls.

The rotation only works if using `app:surface_type="texture_view"` but even then it rotates the controls, which is not good. And I can't use `app:surface_type="texture_view"` because [HDR doesn't look right with `texture_view`](https://medium.com/androiddevelopers/android-hdr-migrating-from-textureview-to-surfaceview-part-1-how-to-migrate-6bfd7f4b970e).

When not using `texture_view` then the video doesn't really rotate and again the controllers get messed up.

So what is the correct way to rotate a video on ExoPlayer?

Comment: AFAIK, you have no choice but to use `app:surface_type="texture_view"`. I can't speak to the HDR problem, but `app:surface_type="texture_view"` with a `Matrix` that applies the rotation (and scaling, etc.) works here. We use custom controls rather than ExoPlayer's own, though.

Comment: Unfortunately HDR looks really dark on CCwGTV when using `texture_view`. I guess I'll ask on the ExoPlayer GitHub. Thanks.

Comment: Just wanted to add that I asked on Github and they said in a future version `surface_view` will be able to rotate and that I am correct about the limited HDR support on `texture_view`, they sent me this link https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/TextureView